# Force JList to NOT wrap at all?

Tags: java, line, jlist, word-wrap

Is there a possibility to force `JLists` to display all items on one line? `setOrientationLayout()` does not give you that option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);
list.setVisibleRowCount(1);
```

Comment: Ah, just what I was after. Thank you very much indeed!