# Display a row of Strings on a JComponent so that the single Strings are selectable/their location getLocation()-able?

Tags: java, string, swing, jcomponent

In order to be able to display a sentence on a, say, `JPanel` with a `GridLayout(1,0)` [i.e., only one line/row] and then be able to draw a syntax tree (or similar) above it, I want to display the sentence as a row of `String`s, which each include one word.

The single `String`s should then be either selectable (as in a `JList`), or I should at least be able to get their Location on the `JPanel` via `getLocation()`.

Up to this point I have tried the following options, and had the following issues:
- Single `String`s as `JLabel`s: The `JLabel`s are stretched out to fill the `JPanel` width, re-sizing them to fit the single `String` they're displaying seems complicated. I would want to be able to do this, however, to make the sentence *look* like a sentence and not like a badly layed out table.
- `JList`: All the functionality I want, but I'm unaware of an option to re-size the "cells" of a single `String` (cf. `JLabel` above). Also, I'm having difficulties restricting display of the JList to a single line/row (cf. [another of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144689/force-jlist-to-not-wrap-at-all)).
- `JTextArea`: I couldn't get my head round how to get the Location of the single `String`s that I had appended to the `JTextArea`.

I'm aware that `drawString()` *might* be an option, but I'm afraid to use it since I don't want to mix AWT and Swing. Also, I would need to calculate the `int` values for `x` and `y` for every single `String`. And I'm not sure whether I'd be able to get their Locations at all (although I could of course save their `int`s in a Map or Vector since I have to calculate them anyway).

Thankful for *any* suggestions! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `JTextArea` and method `modelToView()/viewToModel()` to get x,y for position in nthe string and position in the string for coordinates x and y.

Also use `Utilities` class `getWordStart() getWordEnd() getRowStart() getRowEnd()` methods.

Comment: +1 If I'm not mistaken, this will scale better as the number of lines grows.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As noted by camickr in the comments, `setSize()` is not an appropriate way to lay out Components (as this is automatically done by the respective `LayoutManager`, I have removed the respective code from my answer.

Triggered by [StanislavL's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144809/display-a-row-of-strings-on-a-jcomponent-so-that-the-single-strings-are-selectabl/7145011#7145011), I have found a solution to do it via `JTextField`, albeit by using one for each `String` rather than just one (as suggested by StanislavL).

I can now easily `getLocation()` for each `JTextField`. Simple, really!

I'd like to thank StanislavL for his answer, without which I'd never have though about this, and camickr for his comment.

Comment: -1, Why aren't you using a layout manager? Just use the default FlowLayout and the components will align properly in a row.

Comment: Sorry, but I think -1 is inappropriate. Usually, whenever you are using JPanel, you are using a LayoutManager (see my edit). And of course the components will align in a row, that wasn't what I'm after. In fact, I *am* using FlowLayout. What I wanted was to be able to get the location (via `getLocation()` for each "String" ("componentified" in both StanislavL's and my example as JTextFields)), or be able to make the single *words* selectable. And for this my solution was more workable for *me*, although StanislavL's is obviously just as good, and only triggered mine. Hence I think it's not -1.

Comment: Sorry, I down voted the posting because your code is using setSize() and you said you haven't specified a layout manager which I interpreted to mean that you where using a null layout. However, if you are just using the default layout manager, which is a FlowLayout then the setSize() is not required since FlowLayout will respect the preferred size of the text field. It is the job of ANY layout manager to set the size of a component. You should NEVER invoke the setSize() method. I'll remove the down vote when you remove the setSize() code from the example.

Comment: Ah okay, will remove the `setSize()` code then. I was wondering whether `validate()`ing a component wouldn't be enough for all cases, but haven't checked. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I've simply chosen this as accepted answer because for me it is easier to use several `JTextField`s and `getLocation()` for each (as I need them) than to use one large `JTextField`. **However**, I want to stress that StanislavL's answer is just as valid and will perhaps be more suitable for other users.

Comment: +1 for elaborating. You might still accept @StanislavL's answer, for the reason suggested in my comment on the accepted answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048852/using-jfreechart-to-display-recent-changes-in-a-time-series).